# ACADからIJCADにVBAを移植調査中ですが、 IJCAD VBA で、他の図面のブロックを呼び出して配置する場合の設定方法を教えてください。

Tags: vba

'================================ 他図面からのﾌﾞﾛｯｸｺﾋﾟｰ 有無の確認 ==========================

'下記AUTOCAD(2020)での設定ですが、IJCAD(2020 PRO) の場合はどのように設定すれば良いのか
'教えてください。
'ちなみに、これをIJCADで実行すると途中で、エラーとなってしまいます。
'ACADの部分をGCADに置き換えてもエラーします。

```
Dim OBJDBX          As New AXDBLib.AxDbDocument  'IJCAD での設定はどう書けば良い?
Dim objBlockS       As AXDBLib.AcadBlocks　　　   'IJCAD での設定はどう書けば良い?
Dim objBlockA(0)    As AXDBLib.AcadBlock　　　    'IJCAD での設定はどう書けば良い?
Dim objBlock        As AXDBLib.AcadBlock　　    　'IJCAD での設定はどう書けば良い?
      
Dim blockObj As AcadBlock  'IJCAD での設定はどう書けば良い?

Dim blockRefObj As AcadBlockReference  'IJCAD での設定はどう書けば良い?
      
Dim SSYM As String

SSYM = "BLK1"  '呼び出したいブロック　有無の確認

Dim BLKNAM As String: BLKNAM = "NON"

'  参照元ファイルをｵｰﾌﾟﾝ

OBJDBX.Open "C:\Users\msys-\Desktop\IJCAD2020PRO評価\LIB1.dwg"
```

'ERR  ERR 上の行で"クラスが登録されていません"となりエラーとなります。

```
' ブロックコレクション
Set objBlockS = OBJDBX.Blocks
```

' For Y = 5 To 300　 ' 必要なﾌﾞﾛｯｸを多くｺﾋﾟｰする場合は繰り返す

```
  ' ブロックリストを配列へ
    For Each objBlock In objBlockS
      Debug.Print objBlock.Name

    ' ブロックがあれば
    If objBlock.Name = SSYM Then

          BLKNAM = objBlock.Name
          Set objBlockA(0) = objBlock
    '  ブロックをインポート
    OBJDBX.CopyObjects objBlockA, ThisDrawing.Database.Blocks
    
    End If

  Next objBlock
```

' Next

```
    If BLKNAM = "NON" Then
    
         MsgBox SSYM & "は登録されていません。"
    
        Exit Sub 
  
    End If
    
   
    MsgBox BLKNAM
```

'===================================

Comment: 質問は (コードの) コメント中に埋め込むのではなく、通常のテキストとして投稿した方が見やすいかと思います。質問は後からでも編集できますので見直してみてください。

Answer (score 0):

IJCADでも記載されたソースコードと類似した方法で、図面のブロックを呼び出して配置することができます。

> 'ERR ERR 上の行で"クラスが登録されていません"となりエラーとなります。

IJCADはObjectDBXで図面を操作する機能がない為、その機能を呼び出すとエラーが発生します。
IJCADでは、VBAでObjectDBXを使用せずに図面を操作することが可能です。
その場合は、現在使用しているコードを書き換える必要があります。

IJCADを起動して他の図面のブロックを登録する修正サンプルを以下に記載します。

```
Sub Test()
    Dim objBlockS As GcadBlocks
    Dim objBlockA(0) As GcadBlock
    Dim objBlock As GcadBlock
    
    '図面を新規で開く
    ThisDrawing.Application.Documents.Add
    
    '新規図面のドキュメントを格納
    Dim curDoc As GcadDocument
    Set curDoc = ThisDrawing.Application.Documents.Item(ThisDrawing.Application.ActiveDocument.Name)
    
    Dim blockObj As GcadBlock
    Dim blockRefObj As GcadBlockReference
    Dim SSYM As String
    
    SSYM = "BLK1"  '呼び出したいブロック　有無の確認
    Dim BLKNAM As String: BLKNAM = "NON"

    '参照元ファイルをｵｰﾌﾟﾝ
    ThisDrawing.Application.Documents.Open "C:\Users\msys-\Desktop\IJCAD2020PRO評価\LIB1.dwg"
    
    ' ブロックコレクション
    Set objBlockS = ThisDrawing.Application.ActiveDocument.Blocks

    ' ブロックリストを配列へ
    For Each objBlock In objBlockS  
      Debug.Print objBlock.Name
      
      ' ブロックがあれば
      If objBlock.Name = SSYM Then
        BLKNAM = objBlock.Name
        Set objBlockA(0) = objBlock
                    
        '  ブロックをインポート
        ThisDrawing.Application.ActiveDocument.CopyObjects objBlockA, curDoc.Database.Blocks
      End If
    Next objBlock
    
    '現在のアクティブな図面を閉じる
    ThisDrawing.Application.ActiveDocument.Close

    If BLKNAM = "NON" Then
        MsgBox SSYM & "は登録されていません。"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    MsgBox BLKNAM
End Sub
```